# Visual Studio Crashing in development mode

Tags: c#, crash

I have an winforms application that contains a main form and multiple child forms. When I double click on the main form in solution explorer the form shows up and after few seconds Visual C# crashes:

> Microsoft Visual C#  Express has encountered a
>   problem and needs to close.

It only happens when I open the main form, all the other forms and other items work perfectly fine. When compiled and executed it works fine too. This started to happen yesterday out of nowhere. All I can remember doing is changing the solution name. I wasn't sure if that caused the problem so I changed it back, but still the same thing. It's very hard to work, any suggestions please? Thanks!

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\X64\msvsmon.exe".
>   Dependent Assembly
>   Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,language="*",processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df",type="win32",version="6.0.0.0"
>   could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
>
> Faulting application name: vcsexpress.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time
>   stamp: 0x4ba1faa8 Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x00000000 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
>   0x12026764 Faulting process id: 0xfb8 Faulting application start time:
>   0x01ce2b06d9e82857 Faulting application path: C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\vcsexpress.exe Faulting
>   module path: unknown Report Id: bbcc0a83-9754-11e2-bf54-00038a000015

UPDATE: I tried to open it in VS 2012 and the same exact thing happens..

Comment: Can you post app crash details from the Application Event Log of Windows?

Comment: Maybe restarting the computer might help.

Comment: You can attach a debugger (another instance of Visual Studio) to get a stack trace which may help.

Comment: Do you have version control like SVN? You could try going back to your code base of 2 days ago. If the problem is still there, it not based on the code and all of the answers here can help, starting with the one from @Anri.

Comment: Take a critical look at what's in the `Designer.cs` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting visual studio like this

> devenv.exe /safemode

This will disable addons. Most likely it's one of them causing your problems. After this is confirmed you should try to uninstall addons one by one to see which one is it.

Comment: Unlikely since it's only 1 Form.

Comment: Even more unlikely since it's "vcsexpress.exe" - the Express editions of Visual Studio do not allow the user to install extensions other than templates.

Comment: It says 'Windows cannot find 'devent.exe' when I type it into 'Run' form.

Comment: @user1192403 obviously, you have to go to visual studio installation directory to do that. Smth like "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /safemode" check for the correct path on your disk.

Comment: @Anri I went to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" and there's no such file devenv.exe. only binary starting with D is DDConfigCA.exe thanks

Comment: @user1192403 try "Program Files (x86)"

Comment: @Anri I don't have such directory. I used "Search Everything" application to find devenv.exe but it didn't find anything.

Comment: @user1192403 then go to your vs shourtcut's properties and see where executable is located

Comment: The binary is located at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\vcsexpress.exe" and in that directory there's no such file devenv.exe

Comment: I ran C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\vcsexpress.exe" in safe mode and it still crashes.